# jQuery: draggable connect to sortable. draggable item has a different DOM from sortable list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, draggable

I am now able to drag an item to a sortable. But the sortable list has a different DOM.

```
<!-- The draggable items. Has the "original" DOM in the LI tags. -->
<ul class="draggable_text">
    <li><span>DRAG THIS A</span></li>
    <li><span>DRAG THIS B</span></li>
</ul>


<!-- This list has a different DOM in the LI tags -->
<ul id="stagerows">
    <li><p>This is a new DOM dragged from "DRAG THIS A"</p></li>
    <li><p>This is a new DOM dragged from "DRAG THIS B"</p></li>
</ul>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.draggable_text > li').draggable({
        //helper:'clone',
        helper: function(event, ui) {
            return '<div style="width: 100px; height: 50px; border: 1px solid #000; background-color: #fff;">xxx</div>';
        },
        connectToSortable:'#stagerows'
    });

    $('#stagerows').sortable({
        handle: '.drag_handle'
    });
});
```

The Helper has this:
    xxx
This should be dropped into the sortable...

The "helper" works. But when I "dropped" the item into the sortable, it just reverts back to the "original" DOM. I would want the "newly created DOM" (the one created in helper) to be dropped into the sortable.

I hope I am making sense. Thank you!

Another way of saying it:
when I drag an apple, it now turns into an orange. but when i drop it, it turns back into an apple..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$('.draggable_text > li').draggable({
    helper: function(event, ui) {
        var type = $(this).find('.link_type').val();
        return create(type,0);
    },
    connectToSortable:'#stagerows'
});

$('#stagerows').sortable({
    handle: '.drag_handle',
    placeholder: 'placeholder_sortable'
});

/**
 * When item is dropped from the Add <Stuff>
 */
$('#stagerows').droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui){
        type = ui.draggable.find('.link_type').val();
        ui.draggable.empty();
        return ui.draggable.html(create(type,0))
    }
});
```