# jquery sortable list with different styles div's

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am requiring the functionality of jquery sortable connect lists as per;
[Jquery Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists)

the current functinality drags an image (say AAA) contained in a div from the first list (1) into the second(2),

I would like to know how i can make it so when I drag a AAA from list 1 to 2 ,instead of inserting it into the list 2 it would alternatively insert a different div (say BBB) which has different contents from AAA. Thank you for any help in advance.

EDIT: Id like it also to clone from List 1 to 2 so that AAA persisits in list one and BBB is inserted into 2.

EDIT / ANSWER: Searching this site I found the answer in case anybody wants to know, here it is:

[jquery-draggable-connect-to-sortable-draggable-item-has-a-different-dom-from-so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741226/jquery-draggable-connect-to-sortable-draggable-item-has-a-different-dom-from-so%20%22)

Comment: How is your question different from the one you linked?

Comment: Aha! Answered my own question.... As i was typing the question i was also searching and found the answer and accidentally linked to it instead of the jquery UI Page!

Comment: Good for you ! :) SO is just A M A Z I N G

Comment: You should probably add your answer as an actual answer to this question instead of a comment so that it can be marked as answered.

Comment: @Phil.Wheeler I will be adding it as an answer in an hours time, as im a new user i have to wait 12 hours until i can answer my own question. Thanks again for the comments.